# Identify Non matching records in Join- Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a Lookup table like below

Table MASTER

```
CD SEQ DEF
1 1 A
1 1 B
1 1 C
2 1 A
2 1 B
2 1 C
2 1 D
```

Table INFO

```
SID CD SEQ DEF
1000 2 1 A
1000 2 1 B
1000 2 1 C

2000 2 1 B
2000 2 1 C
2000 2 1 D
2000 2 1 E
```

How should i write a query to say for the SID 1000 using the same CD, and SEQ 
D is missing compared to Master table.
and for the SID 2000 using the same CD,SEQ All master DEF records exists and also extra DEF record E exists which is not there in Master table.

Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `from master full join info where master.def is null or info.def is null`

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. If making `full join on cd and seq` it will say all ABCDE is present on the whole but dont say it is missing in SID 1000 and few missing in SID 2000. Plz help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the combinations of values in CD, SEQ, DEF in the MASTER table are unique, you could write a cross join which gives you all "valid" combinations for the INFO table - see Query1.  Then you could this query, along with a query that returns all rows from INFO, and the [set operators](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries004.htm#SQLRF52341) MINUS and UNION ALL to find the rows you are looking for (see Query2).

**Query1**

```
select sid, cd, seq, def
from 
  ( select unique sid from info )
, ( select cd, seq, def from master )
;

SID CD  SEQ DEF
1000    1   1   A    
1000    1   1   B    
1000    1   1   C    
1000    2   1   A
1000    2   1   B
1000    2   1   C
1000    2   1   D
2000    1   1   A    
2000    1   1   B    
2000    1   1   C    
2000    2   1   A
2000    2   1   B
2000    2   1   C
2000    2   1   D
```

**Query2**

```
select *
from (
  (
    select sid, cd, seq, def, 'missing from info' as comments     -- Query1
    from 
      ( select unique sid from info )
    , ( select cd, seq, def from master )
    minus
    select sid, cd, seq, def, 'missing from info' from info       -- INFO + comment 
  ) union all (
    select sid, cd, seq, def, 'in info (not in master)' from info -- INFO + comment
    minus
    select sid, cd, seq, def, 'in info (not in master)'           -- Query1
    from 
      ( select unique sid from info )
    , ( select cd, seq, def from master )
  )
) where cd = 2 and seq = 1 
;
```

**Result**

```
SID   CD  SEQ DEF  COMMENTS
1000  2   1   D    missing from info
2000  2   1   A    missing from info
2000  2   1   E    in info (not in master)
```

Caveat: In your question, you are saying (among other things) that 
*"SID 2000 using the same CD,SEQ All master DEF records exist"*
although the combination (cd, seq, def) 2-1-A is missing from info.  Query2
will report this combination to be missing.

[Dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f444e6a40d9598aaf26487f187c73ad1).  Table comparison technique described [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1417403971710).